# Meaning in context - "if not where that curiosity comes from,at least how you can best satisfy it"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It seems that basic nosiness is a natural part of the human condition. If it weren’t, why would people watch the endless string of reality shows on TV? Peering into the lives of others seems to satisfy a deep yearning, if not just idle curiosity. It’s perhaps for this reason that so many of us enjoy chatting with strangers when we’re thrust together by circumstance. Whether on line in the supermarket, waiting in a waiting room, or sitting next to a fellow passenger, it seems almost endemic for someone to initiate a conversation. New research shows, **if not where that curiosity comes from, at least how you can best satisfy it**.

What does “*if not where that curiosity comes from,at least how you can best satisfy it*”mean?

Comment: Is there a source for this?

Comment: It is an article I read on psychology today page on Facebook.                           Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New research shows, if not where that curiosity comes from, at least how you can best satisfy it.
That is built on two simple sentences:

New research does not show where curiosity comes from.
New research shows how you can best satisfy curiosity.

The other way to write this is not as elegant:

**New research does not show** where curiosity comes from **but** at least it does show how  you can best satisfy it.

**If not** replaces: **does not show** where curiosity comes from

Answer (score 1):

The new research does not tell you **why** you are curious, but it does tell you how to **satisfy** your curiosity—how to scratch the itch.